# GUIzero: "'int' object is not subscriptable" with variables that are forced to be strings

Tags: python, python-3.7, guizero

I am working on a piece of GUIzero code intended to attach the values of a 2D array to a selection of textbox widgets. However, despite the fact that all variables in the widget value equations are forced to be strings, it still is telling me that a value is an integer.

```
    leaderboard_array = ["***", 0]*5
    leaderboard_box1 = Text(leaderboard_window)
    leaderboard_box1.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[0][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[0][1]))
    leaderboard_box2 = Text(leaderboard_window)
    leaderboard_box2.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[1][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[1][1]))
    leaderboard_box3 = Text(leaderboard_window)
    leaderboard_box3.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[2][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[2][1]))
    leaderboard_box4 = Text(leaderboard_window)
    leaderboard_box4.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[3][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[3][1]))
    leaderboard_box5 = Text(leaderboard_window)
    leaderboard_box5.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[4][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[4][1]))
```

The exact error code is this:
leaderboard_box2.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[1][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[1][1]))
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leaderboard_array[1][0]` is indexing the second item of `leaderboard_array` which is a `0` (which is an `int`). I think you meant to have leaderboard array be a list containing more lists within it, which you can get by replacing line 1 with `leaderboard_array = [["***", 0]] * 5` using two sets of []

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, it seems like the error is coming from this line:

```
leaderboard_box2.value = str(str(leaderboard_array[1][0]) + ": " + str(leaderboard_array[1][1]))
```

Where the error lies is that when you call leaderboard_array[1], the value in the 1st index position of the leaderboard array is an integer of some kind. In your code, by calling:

```
leaderboard_array[1][1]
# or
leaderboard_array[1][0]
```

You are trying to index an integer, which is not possible. I would recommend printing out what leaderboard_array[1] is to get a better idea as to why this error is occurring.